# What is the formula for calculating the amount of money I end up with in a given period (salary and compounding effect)?

Tags: calculation, interest, compound-interest

I'll give a concrete example (couldn't find a similar question):

- Let's say I have an amount of money M at time t = 0 (first month).
- Every month, I get a given amount (let's say constant) of R
- On my total amount of money for each month, I get a return of P percent per month.

What is the formula to know the final amount of money after t months?

Comment: Do you get R at the beginning of the month or at the end of the month?

Comment: @DilipSarwate At end of the month

Comment: So how about trying to figure out, all by yourself, the formula for how much money you will have at the end of the first month, and the formula for how much money you will have at the beginning of the second month (t=1)?

Comment: After one month it's: (M + R)*(1+P)^1
then it's ((M + R)*(1+P)^1) * (1+P)^2.
It's recursive. Don't hesitate to risk being more helpful ;)
My question is for t arbitrary, not t = 1...

Comment: Normally, formulas are here to accomodate EITHER no payment at t = 0 but payment at t = Final, OR payment at t = 0 but no payment at t = Final. Please choose one.

Comment: Well, I don't see why we should restrict ourselves to only those cases. What's your reasonning?
My question relates (among other cases) to the case of a trader who, on average, does a P percent ROI per month on his fortune. At the end of the month, he cashes out (takes the interest) and directly reinvests his total sum and so forth, for t months.

Comment: It is called annuity immediate and annuity due. You can't say that guy gets a Payment in the very beginning AND at a Payment at the very end. It creates a lot of confusion. Annuity immediate, annuity due, and your special case "all inclusive" gives 3 distinct formula.

Comment: @Symeof Do you understand that I am only talking about the initial and final payment? In all three cases, the person receives Payment every month in between. So if there are 12 periods in total, the person will certainly receive Payment at t = 1, 2, 3, ..., 11. What I am asking you is do you want payment at t = 0 or t = 12. You said "At end of the month" in the second comment. Yet the fourth comment shows M+R, implying that the person got R at t=0.

Comment: Your formulas are slightly wrong.  Month1 = (M+R)*(1+P).  Month2 = (Month1 + R)*(1+P) = ((M+R)*(1+P)+R)*(1+P).   The second month's interest isn't squared because it's only over a single month.

Comment: Since R is paid at the end of the month, it is unrealistic to assume that the return applies to this amount also.  The total at the end of each month should be T(0)=M, T(1)=T(0)*(1+P)+R, T(2)=T(1)*(1+P)+R=(M*(1+P)+R)*(1+P)+R  This formula does not reduce.

Comment: @Symeof What you are asking for, and the terminology in your question, suggests that your question is a re-phrasing of a homework problem in a middle-school algebra course. Everything that you have said in subsequent comments reinforces this impression.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the comments.
base64. I see your point.
Derek_6424246: Yes, it's a displacement of one month. Good point.
DilipSarwate: Well, I understand where you are coming from, but you are just wrong. It's purely out of curiosity. And my phrasing comes from my studying of math and computer science. You may want to focus on being helpful, like Alex B and the others, instead of assuming that I'm trying to get you to solve my homeworks. Nothing personal.

Comment: @Symeof Indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the future value of money given:

> M = initial investment
>   R = additional monthly investment
>   P = interest rate earned per month
>   t = number of months

This is the result of 2 formulas.   1.  How much is the initial investment worth at the end + 2. How much are the additional contributions worth at the end.

FutureValue[M] = M * (1+P)^t
FutureValue[R] = [annuity calculation](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/03/101503.asp) = R*((1+P)^t-1)/P)

So the future value of your initial investment with regular additions, all earning the same return monthly at the end of t months will be: M * (1+P)^t + R*((1+P)^t-1)/P)

Comment: How would you modify that to allow for an assumed inflation rate,  to get an "in todsy's dollars" estimate of how much that will actually buy? Just subtract inflation rate from interest rate?

Comment: @keshlam I know that's a good ball park, but I'm not sure if it's 100% correct.    I'd ask that as a new question and see what people say.