# Find ending balance given return rate and amount added each year

Tags: investing, calculation, interest, compound-interest

If I have an investment that grows 10% per year, and every year I add an amount, is there a formula that can be used to find my ending balance after n years?

The following demonstrates this:

```
year 0: B = s*1.1^0 + a*1.1^0 = s + a
year 1: B = s*1.1 + a*1.1 + a
year 2: B = s*1.1^2 + a*1.1^2 + a*1.1 + a
year 3: B = s*1.1^3 + a*1.1^3 + a*1.1^2 + a*1.1 + a
year n: B = s*1.1^n + a*1.1^n + a*1.1^(n-1)... + a

where
    B is the balance at the start of the year
    s is the starting amount
    a is the amount added each year
```

Comment: See if this [helps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698578/compound-interest-formula-adding-annual-contributions)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48063/what-is-the-formula-for-calculating-the-amount-of-money-i-end-up-with-in-a-given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
B = ((a + a*r + r*s)*(1 + r)^n - a)/r
```

For example, the OP's calculation with `s = 1000` and `a = 100`

```
year 3: B = s*1.1^3 + a*1.1^3 + a*1.1^2 + a*1.1 + a = 1795.10
```

Using the formula arrives at the same result

```
n = 3
r = 0.10

B = ((a + a*r + r*s)*(1 + r)^n - a)/r = 1795.10
```

***Derivation***

The OP requires the sum of the compounding amounts, plus `s` with interest, plus `a`

[image]

Replacing the summation with the closed-form expression

from [Wikipedia Geometric series formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas) (which confusingly also uses `r`)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [Investopaedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/compoundinterest.asp)

Compound interest = [S (1 + i) ^ n] – S

- S = Principal
- n = number of years
- i = interest rate